# MSW v0.40 Error: thrown: Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test

Tags: jestjs, msw

I've been using MSW since v0.35.0. Recently I updated it to v0.40.1 and now it seems like MSW is not intercepting the request to the servers and I'm getting the following error.

Here is my test code.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';

const path = 'login/';
const accessToken = 'AccessTokenValue';
const correctCredential = { email: 'test@email.com', password: 'password' };

const server = setupServer(
  rest.post(path, (req, res, ctx) => {
    return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ data: { access: accessToken } }));
  }),
);

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterAll(() => server.close());
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());

describe('Login', () => {
  test('Case: Success', async () => {
    let token = '';
    await axios
      .post('https://test.com' + path, correctCredential)
      .then((response) => (token = response.data.data.access));
    expect(token).toBe(accessToken);
  });
});
```

And this is the error I get.

> Error: Request failed with status code 400

> ```
> at createError (<my_local_path>)
> at settle (<my_local_path>)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (<my_local_path>)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
> ```

Here are the versions of the other packages I use.

- jest: 27.0.6
- axios: 0.25.0

I read [Examples](https://mswjs.io/docs/api/setup-server) from MSW and I don't see any problem with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this issue is relevant.
https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1125

This issues was fixed 5 days ago, so I believe a corrected version will be released in the near future.

btw, downgrading to 0.36.8 is temporary solution.

Comment: Downgrading didn't work for me. I upgraded to version 0.44.2 and now it's working.